# permission_denied at /: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

This is my first time using firebase, and when I try to retrieve data I can't get it to work.

I've implemented the firebase's authorisation and used it and can now see the user's data from any controller (Check controller below), but when I try to retrieve data from the database I get this error:

`permission_denied at /: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`

My database rules regarding the feed are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

If I make them public it works and I get data, but I don't want to do that, and I can't find any documentation online about how do I send the user id to get the data from firebase.

My controller:

```
.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseObject','currentAuth',
    function($scope,$firebaseObject,currentAuth) {

        console.info('currentAuth',currentAuth); // This returns the needed info about the current user including the uid

        // This is where I get the permission denied error.
        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        // download the data into a local object
        $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
}]);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the user isn't authenticated when you attach the listener. Logging the user like you do is not a good indicator for this, since the dev tools of your browser will show you the updated value of `currentAuth` as it changes. If you instead log `console.info('uid',currentAuth.uid)` you will likely see that it's `null`.

You should only attach your listeners once the user is authenticated. From the [AngularFire documentation](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#onauthstatechangedcallback-context):

```
$scope.authObj.$onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
  if (firebaseUser) {
    console.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
    $scope.data = $firebaseObject(ref);
  } else {
    console.log("Signed out");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, when I print out currentAuth.uid it's not null it gives me the value of the user, and that comes up in the log before the error comes.

The value of uid that I'm getting right now is wJMkHNMDcmMz2syU9gakwYevC7J2

Comment: I also added the onAuthStateChanged from the documentation before I post this question and I tried adding the firebaseObject there but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not sure what is causing the error then. But it's quite explicit: you're trying to read/write data when you don't have access to it. I haven't seen that message be wrong in a long time. Can you reproduce it in a jsbin?

Comment: I'll give it a try Frank.

Comment: Frank, i tried another approach and faced the same issue, can you take a look at this post please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690615/cant-get-data-from-firebase-authorization-denied/42690784#42690784