# Can't get data from firebase. Authorization denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm still starting out with firebase and i'm using angularfire to connect.
I was able to do the authentication successfully using google as a provider and I logged in using my account and got back my user details including uid & image, however, when I attempt to retrieve any data I get: `permission_denied at /series: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.` I also tried the simulator and got the same issue.

Here's my database:
[image]

My rules:
[image]

The data I entered in the simulator. I got the uid after signing in using google in the app:
[image]

And the result after using the simulator:
[image]

Here's where I got my UID from: (The authentication tab)
[image]

**What am I supposed to be doing but not doing**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer. As cartant wrote

> there are no read permissions granted, as .read defaults to false

all I needed to do was to `".read": "auth != null"`

So the new rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "series": {
      ".read": "auth != null", << THAT WAS MISSING
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that with these rules **everyone** can read all data under `/series`. The `.read` rule under `$uid` is not taking anyone's permission away. For more on that, see the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade