# How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database with the auth rule on web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a web app on Firebase hosting and I need to read some data from my DB.
I can read any data I want with `".read"` permission.
Eg:

```
{  
  "users": {
    ".write": "true",
    ".read": "true"
  },
  ...
}
```

The above rule works fine but when I set `auth` rule, it doesn't work. Here's my new rule with `auth`:

```
{  
  "users": {
    ".read": "(auth != null && auth.uid == $userId)",
    ".write": "(auth != null && auth.uid == $userId)"
  },
  ...
}
```

The error I got: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

I'm trying to access the data after the user signed in and I'm using prebuilt-ui of Firebase.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (firebaseUser) => {
    if (firebaseUser) {
       /* read the data */ 
    }
}
```

I can also read the user's JTW token and my DB path is correct but still, it's not working.

I found this question: [permission_denied at /: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640011/permission-denied-at-client-doesnt-have-permission-to-access-the-desired-dat)

and I init the app after the user signed in but it didn't work either. So, why is `auth` rule is not working.

Note: This rule works in my both mobile apps (iOS and Android)

My db structure:
[image]

My exact rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        "single":{
          "private": {
            ".read": "(auth != null && auth.uid == $userId)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your database strcuture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no $userId defined in your path. Let says if your the users node contains more children nodes one for each user then your rules should look like:

```
{  
  "users": {
    "$userId" {
      // grants write access to the owner of this user account
      // whose uid must exactly match the key ($userId)
      ".read": "(auth != null && auth.uid == $userId)",
      ".write": "(auth != null && auth.uid == $userId)"
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Now here the value of `userId` is same as the key of that child node which should be the user's UID.

**Updates after a long chat:**
Initialize the 2nd database as shown below:

```
const firebaseConfig = {...}
const app1 = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var database2 = app1.database("https://second-db-url.firebaseio.com/");
```

After this configuration, then make your requests.

Comment: I defined it ad the top of the rule. I'll update the question. Sorry

Comment: @tpbafk yes please update the question with actual security rules

Comment: I didn't want to share it for the company's security things. Updated it now. I want to read `isPremium` field in that private node

Comment: Now I tried to read a public node under this user and it didn't work also. So the problem starts with `"$userID"` but I have the user ID and I'm sure about it because I'm logging the ID before I access the data

Comment: @tpbafk there seems a mismatch or the screenshot is incomplete, because in rules the path looks like `users > userId > private` but in database it's like `users > userId > single > private`.. or is the `"single"` userId of that user ?

Comment: @tpbafk we'll debug it, but can you please a JSON export for me to test that on my side? Just replace the sensitive information with dummy data,

Comment: I edited the question again. It was just a typo. I'll export and share it now.

Comment: @tpbafk that'll be easier for me to test rules

Comment: `{
  "testUserId": {
    "single": {
      "private": {
        "createdAt": 1619451200873,
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "isPremium": false,
        "sessionID": "testSessionID",
        "userId": "testUserId",
        "uuid": "testUUID"
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: This is a user from my users node

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231777/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-tpbafk).

Comment: This guy is a true hero